# No applications available to install on Web Platform Installer on Vista x64

Tags: asp.net, 64-bit, vista64, web-platform-installer

When I use the Web Platform installer on Vista x64 Business it doesn't list any of the applications (such as DotNetNuke or SubText).

Has anyone got it to work on Vista 64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running Vista Home Premium x64 SP2 and can see plenty of web applications with no problem. Is it possible there is some prerequisite software or libraries you need to install (say, using the WPI) before you can install web applications?
The first step I'd take is to uninstall WPI, restart your computer, and reinstall WPI. It sounds so basic but the simplest fixes are so often sufficient.
Is everything on your system up-to-date?

Comment: 'Is everything on your system up-to-date?' - That's the answer. I noticed SP1 for vista wasn't installed, and in the XML for WPI, most applications have 6.0.1 as the minimum required version.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out. I'm neurotic about having the absolute latest software across the board, for reasons like this.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with Vista x64 Business edition. The application catalog is downloaded from the web via http requests. You might try using a tool like Fiddler Web Debugger to determine if the app is able to connect properly. You may have a firewall or network issue preventing it from fetching the list of applications.

Comment: I'm using Business edition and I can't see any. I'll have a look at the HTTP traffic

Comment: I doubt it's that though, as it downloads the list of platform stuff fine.